# Hadoop is sometimes too slow (stuck at 100%)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I set up a cluster of ten machines in which I installed CDH4 (yarn).
I run the nameNode, the resourceManger and the historyServer in the same node, and the client in another node.

On the rest of machines, I turned on dataNode and NodeManager.
I launched my application on a 100GBytes file, it worked at first and it was relatively quick, but now it gets really really slow at the end of the map (around 90% 100% it takes 30 minutes).

I don't know if the problem comes from the way I coded the program or the way I configured cloudera CDH4.
The problem is that it works sometimes but does not work other times although I didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you start multiple jobs on the same setup at any one point of time?

Comment: see logs and check what log say's about it..

Comment: I start just one job, and I checked logs but there is no error

Comment: post your job counters, logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it took so much time at the end, in fact I thought that the command hadoop fs -expunge allows me to empty the trash but it doesn't, so when Hadoop tried to write in HDFS files the result it was very slow because there was a very little space left.